# Can I have some help translating some error messages into tangible information?

Tags: java, class, jsp, exception, jar

When trying to view a specific page on my web site it comes up blank in the browser but in Eclipse a long error message is generated from tomcat.

The page that is coming up blank is not a page I have modified yet.  I have modified some other pages and they are working fine but now that I have modified them this particular page is generating the errors when visiting it.

The error is very long so I'm just going to post what I believe to be the important parts.  If more of the error is needed please let me know.

I've read through the error but I'm not sure what exactly the server is trying to tell me is wrong.

Hopefully some one will be able to point me in the right direction.  Thank you ahead of time.

---

```
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:tunestore' did not find a matching property.
```

---

```
Nov 22, 2011 6:25:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/root/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/tunestore/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.4.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.tunestore.util.DBUtil).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

---

```
Nov 22, 2011 6:25:37 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache tldScanJar
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Nov 22, 2011 6:25:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 50 in the generated java file
The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
.....(continues)
```

---

```
Nov 22, 2011 6:25:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.tiles.comments_jsp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:172)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:370)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
......(continues)
```

---

```
Nov 22, 2011 6:25:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.tiles.comments_jsp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
....(continues)
```

---

```
Nov 22, 2011 6:25:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ActionServlet] in context with path [/tunestore] threw exception [org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: ServletException in '/WEB-INF/tiles/comments.jsp': org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.tiles.comments_jsp] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.tiles.comments_jsp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:132)
.....(continues)
```

---

```
Nov 22, 2011 6:25:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 35 in the generated java file
The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:644)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:358)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
.....continues
```

---

```
Nov 22, 2011 6:25:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve custom
SEVERE: Exception Processing ErrorPage[exceptionType=java.lang.Throwable, location=/error.jsp]
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 35 in the generated java file
The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

Stacktrace:
    at 

org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    .....(continues)
```

And here is the list of my libraries:

```
antisamy-1.4.3.jar
antlr-2.7.2.jar
avalon-framework-4.1.3.jar
batik-css-1.7.jar
batik-ext-1.7.jar
batik-util-1.7.jar
bsh-core-2.0b4.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-beanutils-core-1.7.0.jar
commons-chain-1.1.jar
commons-codec-1.2.jar
commons-collections.jar
commons-collections-3.2.jar
commons-configuration-1.5.jar
commons-dbcp.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-lang-2.3.jar
commons-logging.jar
commons-logging-1.1.jar
commons-pool.jar
commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
derby.jar
derbyclient.jar
derbynet.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
esapi-2.0.1.jar
jaxen-1.1-beta-8.jar
jdom-1.0.jar
jsp-api-2.0.jar
jstl.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
logkit-1.0.1.jar
nekohtml-1.9.12.jar
oro-2.0.8.jar
servlet-api-2.4.jar
spring-beans.jar
spring-context.jar
spring-core.jar
spring-web.jar
spring-webmvc-struts.jar
standard.jar
struts-core-1.3.8.jar
struts-extras-1.3.8.jar
struts-taglib-1.3.8.jar
struts-tiles-1.3.8.jar
xalan-2.7.0.jar
xercesImpl-2.6.2.jar
xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
xml-apis-ext-1.3.04.jar
xmlParserAPIs-2.6.2.jar
xom-1.1.jar
```

Comment: Add the list of libraries in your `WEB-INF/lib` to the question.

Comment: @DᴀᴠᴇNᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ done.  Thanks for letting me know you needed that.

Comment: Remove the jsp-api and servlet-api jars; that may be enough to resolve it. You *must* not include those jars in a web app; doing so can lead to mysterious crap.

Comment: @DᴀᴠᴇNᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ I can't believe it, that did it.  Please answer the question on here so I can give you full credit for your help.  Thank you very much!!

Comment: No problem--it's just something you learn to look for; messages that don't seem related to anything in the app code, but container- and/or tag-related. It's basically like playing Exception Roulette.

Comment: @DᴀᴠᴇNᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ and of course the code I'm trying to integrate into this web app provides those two libraries to use.  I would have never figured that out.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *must* not deploy the jsp-api and servlet-api jars in your web app.

Doing so makes the container go bananas and can cause all manner of error messages, generally not related to anything that makes much immediate sense or that's related directly to your code.

Comment: I am having some very similar log messages.  I can't find a `WEB-INF/lib` folder, but we are using Maven, and the `jsp-api` and `servlet-api` jars are in the `pom.xml`.  Should I remove them?

Comment: @mattblang They should be marked as "provided"; whether or not you need them depends on your project. They should be brought in by any number of other dependencies. They must not be deployed by your app, though.

Comment: Is there somewhere else to check besides `WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: @mattblang Not really, although maybe somebody mistakenly put one in your app server's lib directory in addition to an already-provided version, or... But without knowing what's *actually* happening in your app it's impossible to diagnose.

Comment: I did find a `WEB-INF/lib` folder in `%My Eclipse Workspace%/.metadata/.plugins/...`.  It does contain a jar `servlet-api-3.0.20100224`.

Comment: @mattblang That's probably supposed to be there.